# Limit of maximizer not equal to maximizer of limit

Tags: calculus, analysis, optimization, convergence-divergence

I am looking for functions $f_n,f$ defined on a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ with unique maximizers $\alpha_n, \alpha$, such that $f_n$ converges to $f$ pointwise, but the $\alpha_n$ do not converge to $\alpha$. Any help would be great. I am so far thinking that the functions $f_n$ cannot be uniformly continuous, so the subset of $\mathbb{R}$ cannot be compact, but I am stuggling with coming up with an example. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Take $f_n$ a "wave" going to $+\infty$. Then $f_n$ converges pointwise to zero but the maximum of $f_n$ is constant and positive.

If you allow discontinuities you can write $f_n(x)= \chi_{\{n\}}(x)$ (which is $1$ only at $n$), if you want smooth functions you just regularize $f_n$. In every case the pointwise limit is zero, and the maximums $\alpha_n$ are $1$.

Comment: The OP wants $f$ to also have a unique maximiser $\alpha$, so we should have a bump somewhere in $f$. Perhaps $f(1)=1/2$. (And of course you need each $f_n$ to have that bump as well). The height of that bump needs to be lower than the bumps of each of $f_n$.

Comment: @BenjaminWang: Thank you for pointing that out. I forgot about the maximizer of $f$... The solution you describe solves the OP's question.

Comment: I'm more impressed that you replied to a 7-year old answer by yourself. Where were you when you answered this question? How are you doing now? Did you see that you'll be here one day? (You don't have to reply as these are personal things, but are interesting to think about by oneself)

Comment: Well, I enter mathoverflow quite often and I see a notification when I have a reply on some stackexchange website. I answered this question when I was doing my phd. I was quite active then on this website. Now I'm an assistant prof so I don't really have as much free time for answering new questions, except if I see something that seems really interesting!